# Count number of previously found duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each row is a webpage visit and the datetime of the visit. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'idvisitor': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1],
                   'dt': pd.date_range(start=datetime(2016, 1, 1), periods=7)})
print(df)
```

Now, after sorting by datetime (the example dataframe is already sorted) I want to add a column where the value is the number of elements with the same `idvisitor` previously seen. I.e. how many times have we seen the user with a certain `idvisitor` before.

Example output:

```
          dt  idvisitor  prev_visits
0 2016-01-01          1            0
1 2016-01-02          2            0
2 2016-01-03          3            0
3 2016-01-04          2            1
4 2016-01-05          4            0
5 2016-01-06          1            1
6 2016-01-07          1            2
```

Note that I'm don't want to just count the number of duplicates of a certain `idvisitor` (that's fairly easy), I want the number of duplicates up to the current row, for each row.

How can this be done without an expensive for loop? I have millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'idvisitor' and call [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount):

```
In [29]:
df['prev_count'] = df.groupby('idvisitor').cumcount()
df

Out[29]:
          dt  idvisitor  prev_count
0 2016-01-01          1           0
1 2016-01-02          2           0
2 2016-01-03          3           0
3 2016-01-04          2           1
4 2016-01-05          4           0
5 2016-01-06          1           1
6 2016-01-07          1           2
```